# Javascript TypeError: cannot read property 'species' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript on Codecademy, and I am doing a task where I have to log the species (Homo sapiens) and age of two people. It is returning a TypeError, a type of error I have not seen yet. The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'species' of undefined
```

My code is:

```
function Person(name,age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.species = "Homo Sapiens";
}

var sally = Person("Sally Bowles",39);
var holden = Person("Holden Caulfield",16);
console.log("sally's species is " + sally.species + " and she is " + sally.age);
console.log("holden's species is " + holden.species + " and he is " + holden.age);
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator to create an instance of an object type:

```
var sally = new Person('Sally Bowles', 39);
var holden = new Person('Holden Caulfield', 16);

console.log( sally.species, holden.species );  // "Homo Sapiens"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `new` keyword as told by VisioN.
What happens when you don't specify `new`:

Try to log `this` inside `Person`.

```
function Person(name,age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.species = "Homo Sapiens";
  console.log(this);
}
```

var sally = Person("Sally Bowles",39);

var holden = new Person("Holden Caulfield",16);

> //Logs:
>
> Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location,
>   external: Object, chrome: Object…} Person {name: "Holden Caulfield",
>   age: 16, species: "Homo Sapiens"}

In the first call for `Sally Bowles` `new` is not specified so `Person` is called as a normal JavaScript function and hence `this` is set to `window`.

Whereas, in the second call for `Holden Caulfield` new is specified so `Person` is called as `constructor` function and hence `this` is set to your new object.